# select 'm' from table 1 and return 'male' based on table 2

Tags: mysql

I have two tables here.

Table 1:

```
|    GENDER    |
|      m       |
|      f       |
|      m       |
```

Table 2:

```
|    GENDER    |    GENDER_FULL  |
|      m       |       Male      |
|      f       |      Female     |
```

How do I query to return the results below.

```
|   GENDER_FULL   |
|      Male       |
|     Female      |
|      Male       |
```

Table 1 is my main table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t2.gender_full
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.gender = t2.gender
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select GENDER_FULL from table1 t1,table2 t2
where t1.GENDER=t2.GENDER
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.gender_full
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 USING(gender)
```

is another solution. It is superior to the `ON` solution because you can refer to the `gender` column without qualifying the table. With `ON`, this is not possible.